# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar jaxws-rt de mi proyecto Maven?

Tags: java, soap, servlets, sap, neo4j

Recientemente me encuentro en la tarea ardua de reemplazar la librería e implementación para los servicios SOAP actual que es:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6</version>
<dependency>
```

Actualmente estoy usando `JDK 17` y `Tomcat 9` en un proyecto `servlet` pero usando paquetes de `javax`

algunas librerías sugeridas para el reemplazo son `Apache CXF`, `Axis2` pero no he podido implementarlas de forma correcta.

el motivo del cambio es debido a que la aplicación corre en un servidor `Tomcat 9` pero de `SAP NEO`

Alguien podría ayudarme a sugerirme y darme un ejemplo de implementación del cambio de la librería agradezco mucho su ayuda.